# Why does vkCreateSwapchainKHR result in an access violation?

Tags: c++, vulkan

Okay, so I am very new to Vulkan API, as seen in my last question. I am very confused about why vkCreateSwapchainKHR results in an access denied.

I have tried re-typing the code. I have tried Minimal Viable code. I have also tried initializing the swap chain at different times, but they all seem to not work.

The variables like _sur_capab are surface capabilities were got earlier than this. And, _logicalDevice was just an instance of VkDevice.

```
VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR cri = {  };
cri.clipped = VK_TRUE;
cri.oldSwapchain = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
cri.compositeAlpha = VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_OPAQUE_BIT_KHR;
cri.flags = VkSwapchainCreateFlagBitsKHR::VK_SWAPCHAIN_CREATE_FLAG_BITS_MAX_ENUM_KHR;
cri.imageArrayLayers = 1;
cri.imageColorSpace = VkColorSpaceKHR::VK_COLORSPACE_SRGB_NONLINEAR_KHR;
cri.imageExtent = _sur_capab.maxImageExtent;
cri.imageFormat = VkFormat::VK_FORMAT_ASTC_5x4_UNORM_BLOCK;
cri.imageSharingMode = VkSharingMode::VK_SHARING_MODE_MAX_ENUM;
cri.imageUsage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT;
cri.minImageCount = _sur_capab.minImageCount;
cri.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SWAPCHAIN_CREATE_INFO_KHR;
cri.preTransform = _sur_capab.currentTransform;


vkCreateSwapchainKHR(
    _logicalDevice, 
    &cri,
    nullptr,
    &_swapChain);
```

Answer (score 1):

One advice up front: Always run your applications with the validation layers enabled, they should hint you at the potential problems in your code.

Without knowing the remaining relevant code parts, I can see several potential problems with your code above:

First one is the fact that you're setting invalid values for `flags` and `imageSharingMode`. The `_MAX_ENUM_` values are not be used for initialization, so you need to pass proper values there. Usually it's `0` for the `flags` and e.g. `VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE` for the `imageSharingMode`. Check the specs to see what values are valid for the members of your `VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR` structure.

Next up you need to check if the imageFormat you request is actually supported on your device via `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR`. `VK_FORMAT_ASTC_5x4_UNORM_BLOCK` is a pretty specific format and I can imagine that only a very few, if any at all, implementations support this as a surface format.

It also looks like you're not setting the `presentMode` at all, making it `0` due to initialization, which equals to `VK_PRESENT_MODE_IMMEDIATE_KHR`. This mode may not be supported on your target implementation, just like the image format. You need to either select a present mode that's available everywhere, or properly select one that's supported via `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfacePresentModesKHR`.

Comment: How do you use validation layers? Like how do you make them?

Comment: They are part of the SDK, so if that's installed you just have to enable them. See e.g. https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Setup/Validation_layers for an introduction.

Comment: Wow, validation layers actually help! I just figured out that the surface wasn't defined!